# Magento Addto cart operation

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I am doing a magento customaization site,I am new to magento . My product has model type and model version.I want to pass model type and version to cart page and checkoutpage, So i decided to store the two field in cart table where should i found the cart insertion code for magento and how can i add these two fields in cart table? please anybody help!

I have tried the below code in  addAction() of Mage/checkout/controllers/cartcontroller.php to post the extra fields.

```
$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of finding the magento core code, what you can do is you can write observer for magento events. Like whenever the product added into cart or deleted from cart or if just landed to checkout page or you just placed an order... like this for each and every actions in magento there is an event generated for this... you just need to write the logic in observer what to do ...and also you are getting cart items and all the details of cart in observer object ...

following links may be helpful ...

> > http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page
> >
> > http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/
> >
> > you can search for "events and observers in magento" in google